# Persistently modifying the environment of a Jenkins pipeline from within an sh step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am converting a command line build process to Jenkins for CI and the first step of the command line sequence is to source a script which sets up a number of environment variables and shell functions that the later stages will use.

Ideally I would like to create a pipeline which does something like this where `$FOOBAR_DIR` and `build_foobar` are both defined in `foobar.env`

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Setup env') {
            steps {
                    sh '. ./foobar.env'
                    sh 'echo $FOOBAR_DIR'
            }
        }
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                    sh 'cd $FOOBAR_DIR; build_foobar'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the environment doesn't persist from one `sh` step to the next. Is there a way to allow changes made in one `sh` step to impact the environment of the next `sh` step?

I've thought of the following unsatisfactory solutions:

- Creating a single script that starts off with the source of the file and then does everything else. I'd rather avoid this because having the different steps (build, install, test etc...) in their own pipeline steps makes debugging issues easier.
- Source the file at the start of each sh block. Not impossible but the sourcing does take a non trivial amount of time so I'd like to avoid that if possible.
- Taking the information from the shell script and add it an an environment block in the pipeline isn't practical as the command line build will still be used and so the Jenkinsfile will need to be kept in sync with the script.

Should it matter the file that is being sourced looks like this

```
setenv SOMEVAR some_value

setenv SCRIPTED_VAR `some_other_script --option foo`

switch ("`uname -s`")
    case "Linux":
        # do_something
        breaksw
    default:
        # do something else
        breaksw
endsw
```

Comment: We need to see an example snippet of the file.

Comment: I've added an example snipped showing some of the things that are done in this file.

Comment: It will probably not be possible to parse a shell script and assign environment variables at global scope. If it was key-value format suitable for e.g. `source` then there would be at least one path forward.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your first script output the variables it has set:

```bash
setenv SOMEVAR some_value

setenv SCRIPTED_VAR `some_other_script --option foo`

echo "SOMEVAR=$SOMEVAR"
echo "SCRIPTED_VAR=$SCRIPTED_VAR"
```

You can then capture the script output:

```
def foobar_output = sh (script: 'foobar.env', returnStdout: true)
```

You can then set your Jenkins pipeline environment with that:

```
def vars_to_set = foobar_output.split('\n').toList()
for (def one_var : vars_to_set) {
    def env_key_val = one_var.split("=")
    def env_key = env_key_val[0]
    def env_value = env_key_val[1]
    env[env_key] = env_value
}
```

Once you change the global `env`, it should be reflected in the later stages.